# Download version (v0.12.0.0) is a mess on my OSX.

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I downloaded new version GUI (v0.12.0.0) My current GUI helium Hydra was not connecting and the Daemon was not connecting today when I did this.   This helium hydra wallet has been generally good to use. This new download is a mess and I am not a techie. I had completed the wizard but the Daemon was disconnected and the wallet was not connecting.  I closed it. Then, every time I try to open it, the wizard window opens and I am asked to create or restore a wallet. When I type the menomic seed, it says that the user name has already been used and that I need to type in another user name. The user name that has already been used is the user name that is connected to the menomic seed; they are definitions of the same wallet. So, I have a big mess. The language used is new to me in this field. What do I do?  Do I discard the download into the trash? I am not a techie and the technical answers have a vocabulary that is new to me.  Do you have any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

If you had a wallet on the old 11.x running fine, then you didn't need to run the wizard.  Just select wallet and enter password. So here's my suggestion:

Open the GUI app

If it prompts you for a password (for the correct wallet) enter and go.

If wrong wallet, then cancel and you will be dropped to the 'flag' screen.

Once in the 'flag' screen choose your language.

Then select open wallet from file

Here you will be prompted to load your wallet from a file (standard OSX file open dialog)

Navigate to the wallet (will have the walletname with 'keys' on the end.)
Will probably be in your home folder, but I can't say for sure where it is on your machine.

Select

Enter password

profit.